# Unmounted components still being rendered first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, just a question on `componentWillUnmount()` and `render()` lifecycle method. Below is some code:

```
...
export default class App extends Component { 
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { showMessage: true }
   }
 
   handleChange = () => { this.setState({ showMessage: !this.state.showMessage });
 }
   
   render(){
      <div>
         <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.showMessage } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
         <label>Show</label>
     </div>
     { this.state.showMessage && <Message message="Hello" /> }
   }
}

export class Message extends Component {
   ...
   componentWillUnmount() { 
      console.log("Unmount Message Component");
   }

   render(){
      console.log(`Render Message Component `);
      return (
         <div>{this.props.message}</div/
      )
   
   }
}
```

I trigger the unmounting phase of the `Message` componentby unchecking the checkbox , so I have those in the console output:

> Render Message Component
>
> Unmount Message Component

so my question is:

It is not efficient because the current Message component is going to be destroyed since I don't need it once I uncheck the box. But Message component's render() was still being called, which is unnecessary since we don't really care what content it contains, is it a way to avoid the call of re-render method and just get componentWillUnmount() to be called? I was thinking to use `shouldComponentUpdate()`, but I can stop render() method to be called, but that will also stop `componentWillUnmount()` to be called too

Comment: I copied your code to Codesandbox  here - https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-frog-tdn37 . I dont see any issues as the render is not being called when the checkbox is unchecked. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

When you unmount a component `render` is not executed - only `componentWillUnmount` is called. The `Render Message Component` log is caused by initial render when `Message` is visible:

```js
class App extends React.Component { 
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { showMessage: true }
      console.log("initial render:");
   }

   handleChange = () => { this.setState({ showMessage: !this.state.showMessage });
 }

   render(){
      this.state.showMessage || console.log("unmounting:");
      return <div>
         <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.showMessage } onChange={ this.handleChange } />
         <label>Show</label>
         { this.state.showMessage && <Message message="Hello" /> }
     </div>
     
   }
}

class Message extends React.Component {
   componentWillUnmount() { 
      console.log("Unmount Message Component");
   }

   render(){
      console.log(`Render Message Component `);
      return (
         <div>{this.props.message}</div>
      )

   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```